# Add an id attribute to the highlight tag in Jekyll

Tags: html, jekyll

How can I add an `id="test"` attribute to a `{% highlight %}` tag in Jekyll?

My first shot would be something like this:

```
{% highlight ruby id=test %}
# some ruby code
{% endhighlight %}
```

But it doesn't work.

I need this because I would like to reference the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the only way is :

```
<div id="test">
{% highlight ruby %}
# some ruby code
{% endhighlight %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Heads up, for anyone else looking for this now. You can have it a little bit cleaner with:

```
{: #id_name .class_name }
{% highlight ruby %}
# some ruby code
{% endhighlight %}
```